# R.layout.anylayoutname can not be resolved after copy-paste from another project

Tags: android

When I copy the Different Xml Files From Another Projects(Downloaded From the Net), The R class is not Resolving the Error, because the id is not generated in R.java.There is Some Problem In Accessing The layouts in res folders. What Should I Do in that case?

Comment: Could you post the XML files and where you put them in your project folder? There's probably a syntax error in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean and build your project in eclipse ... this  will solve your problem